# How to use debounce in ReferenceInput AutocompleteInput?

Tags: react-admin

It looks like already exists the prop `debounce` for `List`s in other places but I didn't find a way to use it in an input. For example:

```
<ReferenceInput ...>
  <AutocompleteInput ... />
</ReferenceInput>
```

Is there any alternative for this feature?

Answer (score 0):

`<ReferenceInput>` already debounces requests to the dataProvider when the user filters the options via the autocomplete. By default, the delay is 500ms.

`<ReferenceInput>` has an (undocumented) `debounce` prop that allows top customize that delay:

```
<ReferenceInput
    source="post_id"
    reference="posts"
    debounce={700} 
>
```